# Use DOMXPath to exclude an array of tags

Tags: php, xpath

I am using:

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$xpath = new \DOMXPath( $dom );
```

to modify the DOM of my page.

I can exclude all elements that have an `a` tag using:

```
$xpath->query( '//text()[not(ancestor::a)]' )
```

I would like to exclude a dynamic array of tags like:

```
$array => ['a', 'img', 'code'];
```

Is there a handy way to bundle these conditions?

Comment: I'm not sure how to correctly unpack values from `php` array, but try something like `$xpath->query( '//text()[not(ancestor::*[name()=($array)])]')`

Answer (score 1):

It's just a question of iterative string building. Actually you can automate the iteration by using `implode()` for simple, indexed, flat arrays like yours:

```
$array => ['a', 'img', 'code'];
$xpath->query( '//text()[ not(ancestor::'.implode(') and not(ancestor::', $array).']'))
```

Should produce:

```
$xpath->query( '//text()[not(ancestor::a) and not(ancestor::img) and not(ancestor::code)]')
```